# jquery animate doesn't work on ipad after sleep/resume

Tags: jquery, ipad, animation, ios8.1

I'm seeing a strange behaviour on ipad with ios 8.1.  I have an html/js app where I use jquery animation for transitions.  I use both animation of div position as well as fade in/out effects. Here's part of a simple example:

```
$in = $('#newdiv');
$in.css({position: 'absolute', left: "1024px", top: "0px"});
$in.removeClass('hidden');
$in.animate({left: tx, top: ty}, 400);
```

This works perfectly fine - up to a point.  If, while the app is open, I press the "power" button to put the ipad to sleep and then wake it up again (power button, slide, enter unlock code), the animation doesn't work any more.

I connected the ipad to my mac and stepped through the code in a debugger - every line is executed correctly, but the animation simply doesn't animate - at all.

The same happens to the fadeIn/fadeOut animation.

Here's a [very simple jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qs4x6eyd/) demonstrating the problem.

Note that this wasn't happening on the older version of ios before I updated my ipad to ios 8.1.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE:** this only seems to affect the app when running from home screen icon - when run inside the safari, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a lot of time investigating this, it seems the issue is with the ipad/safari and not the jquery.  I create a minimal test without jquery and using css3 transitions instead of jquery `animate` - and the issue is still present.  I asked [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27346022/css-transitions-do-not-work-on-ipad-after-sleep-resume-when-run-from-homescreen) pertaining to the CSS transition.

I also logged it as a bug with Apple.