# CSS transitions do not work on iPad after sleep/resume when run from homescreen

Tags: ipad, ios8, css-transitions, homescreen

I recently asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27065545/jquery-animate-doesnt-work-on-ipad-after-sleep-resume) about jQuery animation not working on iPad after sleep/resume when run from a homescreen icon.  That question received zero comments and zero answers in the two weeks since I asked it.

I spent some more time investigating, creating small tests to understand what works and what doesn't - and confirmed that jQuery is not at fault here, but rather the mobile Safari.

I created this simple test: http://jsfiddle.net/87r3vfe1/ - which does not use jQuery at all and instead uses plain javascript and CSS transition animation. This works perfectly fine in the actual safari - straight away and after sleep/resume - and works from the homescreen icon when just started.  However after the sleep/resume, the transition animation does not work anymore - and the screen simply changes after the indicated delay.

So, it seems like I actually found a bug in the mobile safari.  Does anybody have any ideas for a workaround?

Here's the code from the fiddle.

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child1">
        <div class="button" id="button1">Animate</div>
    </div>
    <div id="child2">
        <div class="button" id="button2">Animate</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#parent {
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
    position: relative;
}

#child1 {
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: yellow;
    transition: left 400ms ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: left 400ms ease-in-out;
}

#child2 {
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    left:100%;
    background-color: red;
    transition: left 400ms ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: left 400ms ease-in-out;
}

.button {
    border: solid 1px black;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background-color: lightGrey;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Javascript:

```
document.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('button1').onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById('child2').style.left = '0px';
        document.getElementById('child1').style.left = '-100%';
    };

    document.getElementById('button2').onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById('child1').style.left = '0px';
        document.getElementById('child2').style.left = '100%';
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, this was related to (or caused by) another bug in iOS 8, covered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25807711/ios-8-homescreen-webapp-turning-ipad-off-and-on-stops-javascript)

iOS 8.1.1 update fixes this bug, so with iOS 8.1.1 transition animations work correctly again.